# How to benchmark Apache spark -mongodb integration

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I am utilizing MongoDB as a database and thereafter process data retrieved through query  as a result-set to generate analytics .But due to massive volume of data I opted for Apache spark to process data stored in MongoDB collection.I need to evaluate performance of Apache spark MongoDB integration.Please suggest me appropriate methodologies for it.